# Determine position of an object in a region in less than 500 ms using ibeacons

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, triangulation, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a project where I must determine the position of a car traveling at 30km / h in a region using three IBeacons.

To achieve this goal the ibeacons must calculate the position of the car in less than 500ms while today as field testing the calculation is between 4-5 seconds on iOS and between 2-3 seconds on android

Have you a solution that can calculate the position more quickly we can increase the number of ibeacons if necessary.

Comment: You should give an overview of what you are doing in your calculations, so we can see if we can spot any improvements or other approaches.

Comment: You need to say exactly what that 4-5 seconds is measuring. It sounds like a long time, because this sort of calculation should be pretty fast.

Comment: 4-5 seconds is the time that the triangulation determine the exact position , i will have access to the source code in a week